# nginx : configure two internal site on two different path

Tags: nginx

this is my scenario:

A Linux Machine with nginx listener on 443 port exposed on public ip (htps://www.example.com) and two ssh portforwarding versus two local network web server on port 3456 and 6789 internal port. I want use nginx for expose first local webserver on path htps://www.example.com/web1/ and second on htps://www.example.com/web2/.

This is my nginx configuration file:

```
   server {
  listen       443 ssl;
  server_name  www.example.com;
  ssl on;

  location /web1/ {
          proxy_pass http://127:0.0.1:3456/;
  }


  location /web2/ {
          proxy_pass http://127:0.0.1:6789/;
  }}
```

If I try in browser htps://www.example.com/web1/ the first request is ok but on next internal redirect request the browser point to htps://www.example.com/. (404 because location / {...} is non present). The same for web2.
The first $uri_request contain /web1/ but other next no and don't match the correct location.
There is a way to mantain /web1/ and /web2/ path on next uri request?

Answer (score 0):

Your application has to know that it lives under "/web1" or "/web2", respectively, or else ensure that every URI being sent out is relative and never starts with a "/"